# Modeling Wallet Logic in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

I have a question about the task: i need to implement a public static method **getTotalAmount()**, which takes as input a wallet with money in the form of an array of strings and the name of the currency. The method must return the amount of money in the specified currency

**Method parameters:**

**An array of strings** containing banknotes of different currencies with different denominations and the **name of the currency** (a string of 3 characters).

I need to implement this method using control instructions such as **"break"** and **"continue"**.

**How the program should work:**

```
String[] money1 = {"eur 10", "usd 1", "usd 10", "rub 50", "usd 5"};

App.getTotalAmount(money1, "usd"); // 16

String[] money2 = {"eur 10", "usd 1", "eur 5", "rub 100", "eur 20", "eur 100", "rub 200"};

App.getTotalAmount(money2, "eur"); // 135

String[] money3 = {"eur 10", "rub 50", "eur 5", "rub 10", "rub 10", "eur 100", "rub 200"};

App.getTotalAmount(money3, "rub"); // 270
```

**Notice to the task:**

1.To convert a string to an integer, use the **parseInt()** method of the **Integer** class.

2.To extract a substring from a string, use the **substring()** method.

```
var text = "some text";
text.substring(1, 6); // "ome t"
text.substring(7); // "xt"
```

**My code looks like this:**

```
package com.arrays.problem6;

public class Currency {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            }

    public static String getTotalAmount(String[] money,String currency){
        int result=0;
        for(String item: money){
            if(currency==item.substring(0,3)){
                // condition: if the specified rate is equal to the array element that is sliced ​​from 0 - 3 index, then

                // add to the counter what is left until the end of the element, converting the string into a number through parseInt()
            }
            result=Integer.parseInt(item.substring(4, item.length()));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I am completely confused in the implementation of the logic of the getTotalAmount() method. Please help me to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, do never compare `String` using double equal signs `==`. Rather use `a.equals(b)`.

Secondly you can use `a.contains(b)` to check if a String contains another String.

You can then use the length of the currency + 1 as start for the substring to get the amount of money:

```
package com.arrays.problem6;

public class Currency {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            }

    public static int getTotalAmount(String[] money,String currency){
        int result=0;
        for(String item: money){
            if(item.contains(currency)){ // condition
                result += Integer.parseInt(item.substring(currency.length() + 1)); // add to the counter
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

If you're forced to use a comparison to solve the exercise, you can also use `a.equals(b)` instead of `a.contains(b)`:

```
package com.arrays.problem6;

public class Currency {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            }

    public static int getTotalAmount(String[] money,String currency){
        int result=0;
        for(String item: money){
            if(currency.equals(item.substring(0, currency.length()))){ // condition
                result += Integer.parseInt(item.substring(currency.length() + 1)); // add to the counter
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Note that I changed the signature of your static method from `String` to `int` since you're counting numbers and probably want to return the numbers, not the String.

If you have to use `continue` and `break` you could negate the condition for example, so you would check if the item **does not** contain the currency. Then you would use `continue` to skip to the next item.

Comment: yes, i completely agree with you!I made such dumb mistakes!Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more complete example.

```java
public class Wallet {

    enum Currency {
        USD, EUR, RUB;

        public String getName() {
            return this.name().toLowerCase();
        }

    }

    private static final String[] WALLET_1 = {"eur 10", "usd 1", "usd 10", "rub 50", "usd 5"};
    private static final String[] WALLET_2 = {"eur 10", "usd 1", "eur 5", "rub 100", "eur 20", "eur 100", "rub 200"};
    private static final String[] WALLET_3 = {"eur 10", "rub 50", "eur 5", "rub 10", "rub 10", "eur 100", "rub 200"};

    public static void main(String... args) {
        var amounts = new Integer[] {
            getTotalAmount(WALLET_1, Currency.USD),
            getTotalAmount(WALLET_2, Currency.EUR),
            getTotalAmount(WALLET_3, Currency.RUB)
        };
        for(var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Wallet " + (i + 1) + " amount is: " + amounts[i]);
        }
    }

    private static Integer getTotalAmount(String[] wallet, Currency currency) {
        int amount = 0;
        for (var note : wallet) {
            var noteDetails = note.split(" ");
            if (!currency.getName().equals(noteDetails[0])) {
                continue;
            }
            amount = amount + Integer.parseInt(noteDetails[1]);
        }
        return amount;
    }

}
```

So let's breakdown the changes:

1. Instead of using strings for the currency comparison I am using an `Enum` which models the currency -- in our case EUR, USD and RUB.
2. Instead of substringing which uses magic numbers to make assumptions about the start and end index I am using `split` which will return an array containing two strings one for the currency and one for the amount in string form. Note, that I do understand that this is a requirement of your task so maybe you need to change this.
3. Since your task calls for using `continue` and `break`, this is how the iteration is handled here. So in case, this check fails `!currency.getName().equals(noteDetails[0])` we simply using `continue` to jump to the next iteration. Also, note that string equality should always be checked using the `equals` and **NEVER EVER** with `==` as the last one will perform an object equality check and not a content equality.
4. In case the currency is the one we expect we add to the total amount which is returned once the loop finishes.

Comment: yes, it is more complete solution,which corresponds OOP paradigm.Thanks a lot!Now i am see my mistakes.